# Using psql command line terminal program to update database

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

Can someone give the steps to updating my database using psql command line terminal program?

I have created a PostgreSQL database in pgAdmin and I have backed it as PLAIN file (plain-text script). I can't restore that file in pgAdmin. In this [this website](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/windows/how-use-pgdump-and-pgrestore-postgres-plus-tutoria), it says you can execute a plain-text script file using the "psql command line terminal program", to recreate the database and load data.

So I'm just wondering if someone can give steps to doing this so I can update my current database (outside of pgAdmin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run in a shell of your database server as user postgres (or any other user with the necessary privileges):

```
postgres@db:~$psql 
  CREATE DATABASE mydb;
  \c mydb
  \i /path/to/backup.sql
```

Thereby you create a database, connect to it and run the plain text SQL script from the file to restore the contents.

[Details about psql in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)